# Why was this question closed? It has an answer. Objective one

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

Why was this question closed as "opinion based"?

[Why didn't Vader save Luke this easier way in Return Of The Jedi?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/72843/why-didnt-vader-save-luke-this-easier-way-in-return-of-the-jedi)

**James Kahn's novelization was pretty clear on the answer, and it's not in any way, shape or form opinion based.**

Moreover, it's clear that at least SOME users VTCed not on the merits of the question but because they were "annoyed" by the user posting "too many" questions - at least one of which was also answerable but downvoted because it appeared subjective.

Answer (score 2):

My VTC had nothing to do with the user. I just felt that it was very "opinion-based" because it relies on imagining a situation that didn't occur in the film. By the same token, you might ask why the Emperor didn't use his force abilities to pick up the saber (or choke Luke or make his head explode from the inside out).

If you feel that there's a fully canonical answer, I'm happy to give you the benefit of the doubt and withdraw my close vote.

---

UPDATE : Now that I've seen DVK's response, my feeling is that answer supplied by DVK has *some* merit but is still a highly speculative answer to a highly speculative question.

Comment: The questions premise relies on the fact that Vader did something quite counterintuitive (pick up and throw, instead of do this thing that you know, all Jedi and Sith mostly do - stabbey-stabbey, poly-pokey, to borrow a style from Peeves). With the former risky for Vader (as we saw) and the latter a lot less risky.

Comment: I'm very interested to see your answer. My own reading of the text doesn't show any special reason why he'd choose to assault Palpatine with a bear hug

Comment: Same here. I didn't think there would be anything other than "that's just not what happened". Just like that Harry Potter question we had recently "what if the Potter cat was another unintended horcrux?"

Comment: @SQB - I stand ready to mock him if his answer is also opinion-based.

Comment: @SQB - Potter question had no plusible premise. This one does.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the question, I can see why it was VTC'd as opinion-based: It's asking about a hypothetical scenario.

However, the possibility of some other action was there - It's been shown in [another question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/72875/20533) that Luke himself retrieved his lightsaber, so the hypothetical solution *is* possible, and perhaps more sensible.

More importantly though, this is not an opinion-based question.  This is a *character motivation* question - asking why Vader chose to act the way he did (which, incidentally, would be exactly as suicidal as running him through with a lightsaber, since it was Palpatine hitting him with Force Lightning that caused his inevitable death).

We *DO* answer questions based on character motivation, so this question is definitely on-topic.  Though it might benefit the question-asker to change his question title, since 'the right way' is a *very* subjective way of phrasing his question.